# Column showing only one option in Infopath 2007

Tags: infopath, forms-services

I have created one choice column (name: update status) with 5 choices inside the form library in sharepoint 2007. In Infopath 2007, in dropdrop list box (list box entries) I entered "Look up values from an external data source".

Data Source > Add > Receive data > SharePoint Library or List > Inserted Form library name > checked on "update status"

Entries: Select a Field or Group > Selected "update status".

I enabled the form to open in browser (display as a web page). I published the form in form library in sharepoint.

Now, the problem is the the drop down list in the form shows only one option (It does not show all 5 choices). I need your suggestion.

Comment: I've checked it works in 2010. Doesn't your phrase "I enabled the form to open in browser" means that you first created it as client form which means that you attrivuted it "full trust" in order to run and this, in turn, means it should be administrator-approved?